# How can I copy the selected contents of all cells in a DataGrid (including DataGridTemplateColumn) with Silverlight 4?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

With Silverlight 4, I can select one or more cells (or rows and columns) in a DataGrid, hit Control+C and the contents are copied to the clipboard. Which is really cool. Upon Control+V, it can be pasted into Excel or some other editor.

However, the if one of the columns is a DataGridTemplateColumn it's values are blank when pasted. Which makes sense, because it could be anything in the column.

How can I tell the Control+C copy what the value of the template cell should be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out this is really easy if you are using data binding. All you have to do is bind the

```
ClipboardContentBinding
```

property with the value you want copied for this column.

For example:

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Name}" SortMemberPath="Name">
  <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="3" />
     </DataTemplate>
  </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```